# Show that $3=\frac{\phantom{-}1+2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+{2}^{2k+1}}{-1+2-2^2+2^3-\cdots+{2}^{2k+1}} $ for any positive integer $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have found an algebraic identity and the following is a certain result that I have obtained from it:

$$3=\frac{\phantom{-}1+2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+{2}^{2k+1}}{-1+2-2^2+2^3-\cdots+{2}^{2k+1}} \tag{1}$$ for any positive integer $k$.

For example, $3$ can be written as:
$$3=\frac{\phantom{-}1+2}{-1+2}=\frac{\phantom{-}1+2+2^2+2^3}{-1+2-2^2+2^3}=\cdots$$

I don't know if the identity that I have found is known, and I didn't write it in the question because I want to know if anyone has an explanation (that doesn't rely on the identity that I have found) for why it is the case that 3 can be written in that form. So the question is:

> Why can $3$ be written in the form $(1)$ for any positive integer k?

By the way, the identity above for 3 is obtained by plugging in certain numbers, the original identity is a general one.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply rewrite it:

$$\frac{(1+2)\cdot(1+2^2+2^4+...+{2}^{2k})}{(-1+2)\cdot(1+2^2+2^4+...+{2}^{2k})}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula for summation of geometric series, $a+ar+\cdots+ar^{n-1}= a\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r},$

the numerator is $2^{2k+2}-1$ and the denominator is $-1\dfrac{1-2^{2k+2}}{1-(-2)}.$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $\frac ab=\frac cd=3$ then $\frac{a+b}{c+d}=3$.

Now apply that result repeatedly to
$$
\frac{2^n+2^{n+1}}{-2^n+2^{n+1}}=3
$$
for different suitable values of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator is 
$$\frac{2^{2k+2}-1}{2-1}=2^{2k+2}-1=:k$$
And the denominator is
$$-\frac{2^{2k+2}-1}{(-2)-1}=3k$$

Answer (score 0):

The way I would show this, would be to factor:
$$2^n+2^{n+1}=2^n(1+2)=2^n*3$$
And
$$-2^n+2^{n+1}=2^n(-1+2)=2^n*1$$
This means your sum transforms into 
$$\frac {3(1+4+16+...+4^k)}{1(1+4+16+...+4^k)}$$
Which is just 3